# Audacity wav file to mp3

Tags: mp3, audacity

Hi i would like to convert an audacity WAV file to an Mp3 and im having trouble finding the up to date information needed in order to do this do you think you can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Open your WAV file in audacity, and in the audacity program choose 'file->export audio'.  You will need to change the extension of the file manually, but you can choose the mp3 format in the drop-down box in the lower right corner of the dialog.

[image]